# Is there a way to retrieve with telephony the name of the contact sender?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-contacts, telephony

So, I need to retrieve the name of the sender of the message, not the phone number, could that be achieved with telephony? I only found message.address and no message.name, I need it for listening to incoming sms.
The reason for that is because I have a list of contacts that need to be matched with the information from the received message .
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**sms: ^0.2.4**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:sms/sms.dart';
 
 
 class ContactPage extends StatefulWidget {
   const ContactPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
   @override
   State<ContactPage> createState() => _ContactPageState();
 }
 
 class _ContactPageState extends State<ContactPage> {
 
   Future<List<SmsMessage>> getAllMessages() async {
     SmsQuery smsQuery = SmsQuery();
 
     return await smsQuery.getAllSms;
   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Material(
       child: SafeArea(
         child: Scaffold(
           body: FutureBuilder<List<SmsMessage>>(
             future: getAllMessages(),
             builder: (context, snapshot){
               if(snapshot.hasData){
                 return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index){
                   return Text(snapshot.data![index].sender);
                 },itemCount: snapshot.data!.length);
 
               }
 
               return Text("No sms");
 
             },
 
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```